# Git cherry pick into a new subdirectory

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I often have to git cherry-pick from an old project to a new project. The new project hosts all files in a `/server/` subdirectory. This throws off all the cherry-picks as it thinks the files should be, e.g. `/path/to/project/myfile.php` rather than `/path/to/project/server/myfile.php`

Is there a way to resolve this with Git?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because a cherry-pick *is* a merge, Git will sometimes figure this out on its own. If Git does not figure this out on its own, you can try fiddling with the rename-detection threshold level: `git cherry-pick -X find-renames=value`.  The *`value`* can be expressed as a percentage, with a literal percent character, e.g., `50%` (the default), `75%` (tighten rename finding if it's finding renames that don't actually make sense), `25%` (loosen rename finding if it's failing to find renames), and so on.  Or, as long as the value is expressed as exactly two digits, you can leave off the `%` character:

```
git cherry-pick -X find-renames=25 <hash>
```

If your Git is very old, `find-renames` may be spelled `rename-threshold` instead.  Consult your installed Git documentation, specifically that for `git merge`.

If lowering the rename threshold all the way (to `01`; zero just means "disabled" so does not work) does not help, there is unfortunately no easy way to deal with this.  You can turn the commit into a patch—e.g., with `git format-patch`—and edit the path name in the resulting patch, though.

Comment: I havent checked if it works, but the `ort` `subtree` option could be used instead of `find-renames`, like `git cherry-pick -X subtree=server <hash>` in the question's scenario

Answer (score 0):

In case the git root of the old project is in `/path/to/project_old` and the new project has its git root in `/path/to/project_new/server`, cherry-picking from one project to the other is easy:

Assuming both are local paths, you can add `/path/to/project_old` as a remote to `/path/to/project_new/server` (or directly clone from it) and do all the git commands as if `/path/to/project_old` would be a git remote server:

Hope this explains the idea:

```
cd /path/to/project_new
git clone /path/to/project_old server
cd server
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```